# URL Guesser RegExp Optimization

Tags: regex, url, coffeescript

I wrote a rather hefty regular expression to be used in a `coffee-script` project. It is intended to take a big chunk of user text (messages, posts, prose) and find all the potential URLs in there, being as greedy as possible.

```
urlGrabber = ///
  (\s|^)                              # Start after a whitespace or string[0]
  ([a-zA-Z]+\://)?                    # Captures any protocol (just not //)
  (\w+:\w+@)?                         # Username:Password
  ([a-zA-Z\d-]|[a-zA-Z\d-]\.)*        # Subdomains
  [a-zA-Z\d-]{2,}                     # Domain name
  \.                                  # THE DOT
  ([a-zA-Z]{2,4}(:\d+)?)              # Domain Extension with Port
  ([/\?\#][\S/]*)*                    # Some Request, greedy capture
  \b                                  # Last word boundary
  /?                                  # Optional trailing Slash
///g
```

I am running into problems with string like `abc.mno.st.u.xvy` where `abs.mno.st` gets parsed as a string. This should not be captured at all. Same goes for `as.ds.d.` where `as.ds` gets captured.

Could anyone please explain why this is happening and/or help out with the changes needed to fix that?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you don't want to match. Would adding a whitespace `\s` at the end solve your problem?

Comment: it helps, but it seems to eat up my trailing whitespace. how can i match yet not consume those trailing `\s` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex pattern

```
(?:\s+|^)                                                   # leading spaces
([a-zA-Z]+://|)                                             # protocol
(\w+:\w+@|)                                                 # username:password@
((?:[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:-[a-zA-Z\d]+)*\.)*)                       # subdomain(s)
([a-zA-Z\d]+(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-(?=[a-zA-Z\d]))*[a-zA-Z\d])      # domain
(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})                                           # .top-level-domain
(:\d+|)                                                     # :port
(/\S*|)                                                     # rest of url
(?!\S)
```

**Note:** Subdomains and domain cannot start and ends with `-` and there should be no double `--` as well (unless you want to support [Punnycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) for [IDN domain names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name)).

Comment: The `(?<=[a-zA-Z\d])` parts seem to break my regexp parser. Can you explain those a bit please?

Comment: @arvidkahl - That is a positive lookbehind. Some compilers do not support this regex feature. I have updated my answer with solution that does not use lookbehind.